# I get NoClassDefFoundError when I try to load an external java file

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

so here's the case... I try to create a class object (to use the method getDeclaredConstructors on it) out of a java file, I load the file with the help of the library net.openhft.compiler and the line looks like : `Class<?> clazz = CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava(fileName, IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(file)));`. When I run the app in Intellij it works completely fine but when i make a jar out of the app and try to do the same I get the Error Message:

> > Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/openhft/compiler/CompilerUtils
> >             at com.company.Modules.ChangeVariableNameModule.storeConstructors(ChangeVariableNameModule.java:530)
> >             at com.company.Modules.ChangeVariableNameModule.changeVariableNames(ChangeVariableNameModule.java:85)
> >             at com.company.Obfuscator.obfuscate(Obfuscator.java:53)
> >             at com.company.View$7.handle(View.java:242)
> >             at com.company.View$7.handle(View.java:210)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown
> >     Source)
> >             at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
> >             at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
> >             at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.openhft.compiler.CompilerUtils
> >             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >             at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >             ... 52 more

I read some stuff about this Exception, do I have to set the classpath to the location where my app is? And if yes, is it possible to do this also in java? - Maybe something with Runtime.exec()?

Or is there a better way to do that? I tried already many ways but I just don't get how to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are all the required classes included in the jar? (you can open it to view the contents using most standard archiving programs)